# Как каждому label присвоить свой цвет?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

Есть **`77`** расставленных лейблов, которые будут добавляться и нужно как-то с ними взаимодействовать, а именно менять им цвет. 
Цвет определяется системно - красный\оранжевый\зелёный.

У всех лейблов цвет серый потому, что у самой программы цвет серый, а задача состоит в том, что нужно каждому лейблу по отдельности присвоить свой цвет в соответствии с номером лейбла, на пример - `label_45` зелёного цвета, `label_52` оранжевого цвета и т.д.

Есть возможность достать нужную цифру, туже **`45`**, но её ещё нужно как-то связать c `label_45`

Они добавлены через *Qt Designer*, могу дать код получаемый **`.ui`**, добавляться должны будут системно, тоже будущая проблема

Выглядит это как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть другие мысли по этому поводу, то всегда рад выслушать!

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from des import *

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**des.py**

pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(818, 469)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/ico/Python.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:#b2b2b2;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 691, 383))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Снимок.PNG);")
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_51 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_51.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(177, 353, 10, 10))
        self.label_51.setText("")
        self.label_51.setObjectName("label_51")
        self.label_46 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_46.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(147, 345, 10, 10))
        self.label_46.setText("")
        self.label_46.setObjectName("label_46")
        self.label_41 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_41.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(126, 289, 10, 10))
        self.label_41.setText("")
        self.label_41.setObjectName("label_41")
        self.label_37 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_37.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 281, 10, 10))
        self.label_37.setText("")
        self.label_37.setObjectName("label_37")
        self.label_36 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_36.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 287, 10, 10))
        self.label_36.setText("")
        self.label_36.setObjectName("label_36")
        self.label_50 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_50.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(94, 271, 10, 10))
        self.label_50.setText("")
        self.label_50.setObjectName("label_50")
        self.label_40 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_40.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(123, 247, 10, 10))
        self.label_40.setText("")
        self.label_40.setObjectName("label_40")
        self.label_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(132, 238, 10, 10))
        self.label_23.setText("")
        self.label_23.setObjectName("label_23")
        self.label_54 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_54.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(134, 321, 10, 10))
        self.label_54.setText("")
        self.label_54.setObjectName("label_54")
        self.label_55 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_55.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(194, 270, 10, 10))
        self.label_55.setText("")
        self.label_55.setObjectName("label_55")
        self.label_56 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_56.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(147, 252, 10, 10))
        self.label_56.setText("")
        self.label_56.setObjectName("label_56")
        self.label_57 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_57.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(96, 251, 10, 10))
        self.label_57.setText("")
        self.label_57.setObjectName("label_57")
        self.label_58 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_58.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(107, 308, 10, 10))
        self.label_58.setText("")
        self.label_58.setObjectName("label_58")
        self.label_28 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_28.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(88, 238, 10, 10))
        self.label_28.setText("")
        self.label_28.setObjectName("label_28")
        self.label_42 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_42.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(116, 265, 10, 10))
        self.label_42.setText("")
        self.label_42.setObjectName("label_42")
        self.label_35 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_35.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 257, 10, 10))
        self.label_35.setText("")
        self.label_35.setObjectName("label_35")
        self.label_68 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_68.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 290, 10, 10))
        self.label_68.setText("")
        self.label_68.setObjectName("label_68")
        self.label_64 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_64.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 299, 10, 10))
        self.label_64.setText("")
        self.label_64.setObjectName("label_64")
        self.label_66 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_66.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(198, 308, 10, 10))
        self.label_66.setText("")
        self.label_66.setObjectName("label_66")
        self.label_69 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_69.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(105, 295, 10, 10))
        self.label_69.setText("")
        self.label_69.setObjectName("label_69")
        self.label_67 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_67.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 321, 10, 10))
        self.label_67.setText("")
        self.label_67.setObjectName("label_67")
        self.label_25 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_25.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(78, 327, 10, 10))
        self.label_25.setText("")
        self.label_25.setObjectName("label_25")
        self.label_63 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_63.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(127, 349, 10, 10))
        self.label_63.setText("")
        self.label_63.setObjectName("label_63")
        self.label_65 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_65.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 213, 10, 10))
        self.label_65.setText("")
        self.label_65.setObjectName("label_65")
        self.label_59 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_59.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(109, 221, 10, 10))
        self.label_59.setText("")
        self.label_59.setObjectName("label_59")
        self.label_30 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_30.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(205, 204, 10, 10))
        self.label_30.setText("")
        self.label_30.setObjectName("label_30")
        self.label_47 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_47.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(186, 227, 10, 10))
        self.label_47.setText("")
        self.label_47.setObjectName("label_47")
        self.label_48 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_48.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(198, 221, 10, 10))
        self.label_48.setText("")
        self.label_48.setObjectName("label_48")
        self.label_29 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_29.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(226, 207, 10, 10))
        self.label_29.setText("")
        self.label_29.setObjectName("label_29")
        self.label_39 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_39.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(207, 250, 10, 10))
        self.label_39.setText("")
        self.label_39.setObjectName("label_39")
        self.label_38 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_38.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 242, 10, 10))
        self.label_38.setText("")
        self.label_38.setObjectName("label_38")
        self.label_43 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_43.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(193, 183, 10, 10))
        self.label_43.setText("")
        self.label_43.setObjectName("label_43")
        self.label_33 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_33.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(205, 175, 10, 10))
        self.label_33.setText("")
        self.label_33.setObjectName("label_33")
        self.label_52 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_52.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(194, 149, 10, 10))
        self.label_52.setText("")
        self.label_52.setObjectName("label_52")
        self.label_27 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_27.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(203, 164, 10, 10))
        self.label_27.setText("")
        self.label_27.setObjectName("label_27")
        self.label_32 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_32.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 210, 10, 10))
        self.label_32.setText("")
        self.label_32.setObjectName("label_32")
        self.label_53 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_53.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(132, 204, 10, 10))
        self.label_53.setText("")
        self.label_53.setObjectName("label_53")
        self.label_49 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_49.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(84, 84, 10, 10))
        self.label_49.setText("")
        self.label_49.setObjectName("label_49")
        self.label_60 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_60.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(191, 88, 10, 10))
        self.label_60.setText("")
        self.label_60.setObjectName("label_60")
        self.label_45 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_45.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 80, 10, 10))
        self.label_45.setText("")
        self.label_45.setObjectName("label_45")
        self.label_62 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_62.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(85, 132, 10, 10))
        self.label_62.setText("")
        self.label_62.setObjectName("label_62")
        self.label_61 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_61.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 114, 10, 10))
        self.label_61.setText("")
        self.label_61.setObjectName("label_61")
        self.label_70 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_70.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 154, 10, 10))
        self.label_70.setText("")
        self.label_70.setObjectName("label_70")
        self.label_24 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_24.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 180, 10, 10))
        self.label_24.setText("")
        self.label_24.setObjectName("label_24")
        self.label_71 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_71.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(111, 178, 10, 10))
        self.label_71.setText("")
        self.label_71.setObjectName("label_71")
        self.label_74 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_74.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(178, 131, 10, 10))
        self.label_74.setText("")
        self.label_74.setObjectName("label_74")
        self.label_26 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_26.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 123, 10, 10))
        self.label_26.setText("")
        self.label_26.setObjectName("label_26")
        self.label_44 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_44.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 150, 10, 10))
        self.label_44.setText("")
        self.label_44.setObjectName("label_44")
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 144, 10, 10))
        self.label_21.setText("")
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.label_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 154, 10, 10))
        self.label_22.setText("")
        self.label_22.setObjectName("label_22")
        self.label_31 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_31.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(317, 142, 10, 10))
        self.label_31.setText("")
        self.label_31.setObjectName("label_31")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(307, 157, 10, 10))
        self.label_12.setText("")
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(282, 113, 10, 10))
        self.label_14.setText("")
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.label_77 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_77.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(356, 124, 10, 10))
        self.label_77.setText("")
        self.label_77.setObjectName("label_77")
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(347, 125, 10, 10))
        self.label_18.setText("")
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 126, 10, 10))
        self.label_16.setText("")
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(395, 148, 10, 10))
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_72 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_72.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(368, 158, 10, 10))
        self.label_72.setText("")
        self.label_72.setObjectName("label_72")
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(436, 142, 10, 10))
        self.label_19.setText("")
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(405, 150, 10, 10))
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_34 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_34.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(417, 135, 10, 10))
        self.label_34.setText("")
        self.label_34.setObjectName("label_34")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 140, 10, 10))
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(455, 120, 10, 10))
        self.label_11.setText("")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(445, 120, 10, 10))
        self.label_15.setText("")
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 98, 10, 10))
        self.label_20.setText("")
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(501, 103, 10, 10))
        self.label_6.setText("")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_73 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_73.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(424, 120, 10, 10))
        self.label_73.setText("")
        self.label_73.setObjectName("label_73")
        self.label_76 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_76.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(408, 114, 10, 10))
        self.label_76.setText("")
        self.label_76.setObjectName("label_76")
        self.label_75 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_75.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(506, 66, 10, 10))
        self.label_75.setText("")
        self.label_75.setObjectName("label_75")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(435, 110, 10, 10))
        self.label_5.setText("")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(457, 107, 10, 10))
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(518, 67, 10, 10))
        self.label_13.setText("")
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 33, 10, 10))
        self.label_8.setText("")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setToolTip("")
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 5, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #FFAA00;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(75, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(291, 0))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 16777215))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 1, 4, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(54, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(153, 243, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 4, 2, 1, 2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem4, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(69, 31))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem5, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 297, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem6, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 818, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Лог панель"))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Изменение ip и данных"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Настройка ip"))
        self.pushButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Пинг старт/стоп"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Yi"))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Отчистить поле лог панели"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить таблицу"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Updae"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг ip"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip аддреса"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Порты"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
import rec_rs
```

**rec_rs.py** - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ea4f_gtf-DpO6Q

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Вероятно, правильнее было бы создавать лейблы динамически, при работе программы, а не хардкодить их при ее создании. Тогда и цвета могли бы расставить, и прочие свойства (типа положения, текста, и т.п.)

Comment: @Kromster Вот только как их расставить на нужные места ну и собственно манипулировать ими

Comment: @Kromster есть мысли о добавлении в бд их координат, но будут ли они подстравиваться под нужные места, если сделать на весь экран

Comment: Точно так же как вы сейчас их расставили (на глаз? или скопировали положения из другого источника?)

Comment: @Kromster Скрин с уже расставленными и на их места свои )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать класс **`Label`** и прописать в нем все что вам надо.

Обратите внимание на `label_45`, `label_51` и `label_52` и попробуйте их покликать. Тоже самое вам надо сделать и с другими `label`. 
Если у вас будут другие вопросы - зададите новый вопрос.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from des import *
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(818, 469)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
# установите свое                     vvvvvvvvv 
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("music.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:#b2b2b2;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 691, 383))
# установите свое                                     vvvvvvvvv 
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(temp_.png);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
#        self.label_51 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_51 = Label(parent=self.tab)                            # +++ 
        self.label_51.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(177, 353, 10, 10))
        self.label_51.setObjectName("label_51")
        self.label_46 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_46.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(147, 345, 10, 10))
        self.label_46.setObjectName("label_46")
        self.label_41 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_41.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(126, 289, 10, 10))
        self.label_41.setObjectName("label_41")
        self.label_37 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_37.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 281, 10, 10))
        self.label_37.setObjectName("label_37")
        self.label_36 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_36.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 287, 10, 10))
        self.label_36.setObjectName("label_36")
        self.label_50 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_50.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(94, 271, 10, 10))
        self.label_50.setObjectName("label_50")
        self.label_40 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_40.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(123, 247, 10, 10))
        self.label_40.setObjectName("label_40")
        self.label_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(132, 238, 10, 10))
        self.label_23.setObjectName("label_23")
        self.label_54 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_54.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(134, 321, 10, 10))
        self.label_54.setObjectName("label_54")
        self.label_55 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_55.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(194, 270, 10, 10))
        self.label_55.setObjectName("label_55")
        self.label_56 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_56.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(147, 252, 10, 10))
        self.label_56.setObjectName("label_56")
        self.label_57 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_57.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(96, 251, 10, 10))
        self.label_57.setObjectName("label_57")
        self.label_58 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_58.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(107, 308, 10, 10))
        self.label_58.setObjectName("label_58")
        self.label_28 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_28.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(88, 238, 10, 10))
        self.label_28.setObjectName("label_28")
        self.label_42 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_42.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(116, 265, 10, 10))
        self.label_42.setObjectName("label_42")
        self.label_35 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_35.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 257, 10, 10))
        self.label_35.setObjectName("label_35")
        self.label_68 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_68.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 290, 10, 10))
        self.label_68.setObjectName("label_68")
        self.label_64 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_64.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 299, 10, 10))
        self.label_64.setObjectName("label_64")
        self.label_66 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_66.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(198, 308, 10, 10))
        self.label_66.setObjectName("label_66")
        self.label_69 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_69.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(105, 295, 10, 10))
        self.label_69.setObjectName("label_69")
        self.label_67 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_67.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 321, 10, 10))
        self.label_67.setObjectName("label_67")
        self.label_25 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_25.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(78, 327, 10, 10))
        self.label_25.setObjectName("label_25")
        self.label_63 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_63.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(127, 349, 10, 10))
        self.label_63.setObjectName("label_63")
        self.label_65 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_65.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 213, 10, 10))
        self.label_65.setObjectName("label_65")
        self.label_59 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_59.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(109, 221, 10, 10))
        self.label_59.setObjectName("label_59")
        self.label_30 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_30.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(205, 204, 10, 10))
        self.label_30.setObjectName("label_30")
        self.label_47 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_47.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(186, 227, 10, 10))
        self.label_47.setObjectName("label_47")
        self.label_48 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_48.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(198, 221, 10, 10))
        self.label_48.setObjectName("label_48")
        self.label_29 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_29.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(226, 207, 10, 10))
        self.label_29.setObjectName("label_29")
        self.label_39 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_39.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(207, 250, 10, 10))
        self.label_39.setObjectName("label_39")
        self.label_38 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_38.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 242, 10, 10))
        self.label_38.setObjectName("label_38")
        self.label_43 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_43.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(193, 183, 10, 10))
        self.label_43.setObjectName("label_43")
        self.label_33 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_33.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(205, 175, 10, 10))
        self.label_33.setObjectName("label_33")
        
#        self.label_52 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_52 = Label(parent=self.tab)                       # +++ 
        self.label_52.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(194, 149, 10, 10))
        self.label_52.setObjectName("label_52")
        self.label_27 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_27.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(203, 164, 10, 10))
        self.label_27.setObjectName("label_27")
        self.label_32 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_32.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 210, 10, 10))
        self.label_32.setObjectName("label_32")
        self.label_53 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_53.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(132, 204, 10, 10))
        self.label_53.setObjectName("label_53")
        self.label_49 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_49.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(84, 84, 10, 10))
        self.label_49.setObjectName("label_49")
        self.label_60 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_60.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(191, 88, 10, 10))
        self.label_60.setObjectName("label_60")
#        self.label_45 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_45 = Label(parent=self.tab)                     # +++
        self.label_45.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 80, 10, 10))
        self.label_45.setObjectName("label_45")
        self.label_62 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_62.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(85, 132, 10, 10))
        self.label_62.setObjectName("label_62")
        self.label_61 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_61.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 114, 10, 10))
        self.label_61.setObjectName("label_61")
        self.label_70 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_70.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 154, 10, 10))
        self.label_70.setObjectName("label_70")
        self.label_24 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_24.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 180, 10, 10))
        self.label_24.setObjectName("label_24")
        self.label_71 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_71.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(111, 178, 10, 10))
        self.label_71.setObjectName("label_71")
        self.label_74 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_74.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(178, 131, 10, 10))
        self.label_74.setObjectName("label_74")
        self.label_26 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_26.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 123, 10, 10))
        self.label_26.setObjectName("label_26")
        self.label_44 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_44.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 150, 10, 10))
        self.label_44.setObjectName("label_44")
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 144, 10, 10))
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.label_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 154, 10, 10))
        self.label_22.setObjectName("label_22")
        self.label_31 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_31.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(317, 142, 10, 10))
        self.label_31.setObjectName("label_31")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(307, 157, 10, 10))
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(282, 113, 10, 10))
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.label_77 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_77.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(356, 124, 10, 10))
        self.label_77.setObjectName("label_77")
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(347, 125, 10, 10))
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 126, 10, 10))
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(395, 148, 10, 10))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_72 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_72.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(368, 158, 10, 10))
        self.label_72.setObjectName("label_72")
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(436, 142, 10, 10))
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(405, 150, 10, 10))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_34 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_34.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(417, 135, 10, 10))
        self.label_34.setObjectName("label_34")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 140, 10, 10))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(455, 120, 10, 10))
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(445, 120, 10, 10))
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 98, 10, 10))
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(501, 103, 10, 10))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_73 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_73.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(424, 120, 10, 10))
        self.label_73.setObjectName("label_73")
        self.label_76 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_76.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(408, 114, 10, 10))
        self.label_76.setObjectName("label_76")
        self.label_75 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_75.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(506, 66, 10, 10))
        self.label_75.setObjectName("label_75")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(435, 110, 10, 10))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(457, 107, 10, 10))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(518, 67, 10, 10))
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 33, 10, 10))
        self.label_8.setText("")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setToolTip("")
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 5, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #FFAA00;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(75, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(291, 0))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 16777215))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 1, 4, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(54, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(153, 243, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 4, 2, 1, 2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem4, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(69, 31))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem5, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 297, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem6, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 818, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Лог панель"))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Изменение ip и данных"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Настройка ip"))
        self.pushButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Пинг старт/стоп"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Yi"))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Отчистить поле лог панели"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить таблицу"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Updae"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг ip"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip аддреса"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Порты"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        
# vvv раскомментируйте         
#import rec_rs


# +++ vvv
class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
    
    def __init__(
        self, 
        background=QColor("white"), 
        foreground=QColor("black"), 
        parent=None
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._background = background
        self._foreground = foreground
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setFont(QFont("Arial", 7))
        self._change_stylesheet()

    @property
    def background(self):
        return self._background

    @background.setter
    def background(self, color):
        if self._background == color:
            return
        self._background = color
        self._change_stylesheet()

    @property
    def foreground(self):
        return self._foreground

    @foreground.setter
    def foreground(self, color):
        if self._foreground == color:
            return
        self._foreground = color
        self._change_stylesheet()

    def _change_stylesheet(self):
        qss = "QLabel {color:%s;background-color:%s}" % (
            self.background.name(),
            self.foreground.name(),
        )
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit(self.objectName(), self.text())


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.label_45.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel) 
        self.ui.label_45.setText("45")
        self.ui.label_45.background = QColor("#295939")
        self.ui.label_45.foreground = QColor("#adeecf")
        self.ui.label_45.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel)                 
        self.ui.label_51.setText("51")
        self.ui.label_51.background = QColor("#fff600")
        self.ui.label_51.foreground = QColor("blue")
        self.ui.label_51.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel)                 
        self.ui.label_52.setText("52")
        self.ui.label_52.background = QColor("#ffefcf")
        self.ui.label_52.foreground = QColor("#ff7a00")
        self.ui.label_52.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel)                 

    def onClickLabel(self, objName, text):
        print(f'Вы кликнули: objName={objName}, text={text}')
# +++ ^^^

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]